# Dialogflow API V2 unity SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, dialogflow-es

Is there any workaround for using the new version (V2) of Dialogflow API in Unity? There used to be a SDK for the previous version but apparently it will be discontinued next year...

Comment: I read somewhere that the V1 API will be around indefinitely and not discontinued in April 2019 as previously announced. That being said, where is the Unity SDK for v2?

Comment: I am also stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no official Dialogflow-Unity-SDK, you can use the Google.Api.Dialogflow.v2 library.

Details at 
[Authenticating Request with Google.Apis.DialogFlow.V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607901/authenticating-request-with-google-apis-dialogflow-v2#new-answer)

Note: Remember that you can't use your token anymore. You need to create a credential file: Details at: https://medium.com/@tzahi/how-to-setup-dialogflow-v2-authentication-programmatically-with-node-js-b37fa4815d89

Comment: There is discussion wheter you should use Google.Cloud.Dialogflow or Google.Api.Dialogflow. For me, only Google.Api.Dialogflow worked in Unity.